# niceScroll don't working on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm using [niceScroll jQuery plugin](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) for my content. My content id #node-10 and here is CSS:

```
#node-10{
    height: 200px;
    width: 370px;
}
#node-10 p{
    padding-top:0;
    margin-top:-3px;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

And JS:

```
var nice = $("html").niceScroll({cursorborder:"",autohidemode:"false",cursorcolor:"##0076A3"});  // The document page (body)

  $("#div1").html($("#div1").html()+' '+nice.version);

    $("#node-10").niceScroll({cursorborder:"",autohidemode:false,cursorcolor:"red",boxzoom:true}); // First scrollable DIV
```

And refresh my site. Scroll don't visible on page load but when click on my content, get scrollbar. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if the same issue you faced.

Check color cursor setting for main page, you wrote erroneously with two hash characters "##".

Try correct with cursorcolor:"#0076A3"

```
$("#node-10").niceScroll({cursorborder:"",autohidemode:false,cursorcolor:"red",boxzoom:true});
```

You can found a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/29W4m/

Comment: Why clickable this content?

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow:auto; for the div first